# creating a linked drop down system in a page using drupal module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Can anyone please tell me is there any module in drupal that I can install to get a linked drop down menu system within a page like this [page](http://intranet.nitrkl.ac.in/student_directory.asp?seltype=2)  ?
Or else can you tell me how to do this kind create this kind of system in existing drupal theme?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with Views.  It will display sorted info like that if you expose the filter for the field you want to sort with